# Imageview doesn't display my icon in Actionbar?

Tags: android, xml, icons, manifest

I have simple image view app... That is suppose to display the image in viewpager mode. However, my problem is that it is not displaying my app icon at the top of the action bar...Any help will be appreciated.....I know that it is something really small, but I can't spot it..I woulde like to display my icon as shown in this [link](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ev_uYXdpwF8/UXbpuJCaRFI/AAAAAAAAHz8/C-I7IlU7ANc/s1600/AndroidDualMode_BACK_ICON.png)

Please see my following codes...

Mainactivity.java

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate menu resource file.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

                // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
                MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

                // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
                mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
                // Return true to display menu
                return true;
        }

        // Call to update the share intent
        private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
                if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
                        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
                }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                oursong.release();
        }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" >

          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
          android:id="@+id/view_pager"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" 
         android:icon="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <!-- Splash screen -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post an image what it look like and what you would like it to be. a link to picture.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin...thanks you for replying..please see my edited link..for my desired action bar..with my icon..

Comment: you mean the android icon?? also can you post an image what it looks like right now

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin....yes just regular android icon..Sorry I am not able to post the image.... I don't know why my emulator is not working properly......

Comment: try this in your manifest `ic_launcher` as the icon

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin..still not working..I named my icon under drawable file as "icon"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you only need edit a file in a folder called **menu.** Your file looks like

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item
     android:id="@+id/action_settings"
     android:orderInCategory="100"
     android:showAsAction="never"
     android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

and just change **never** and put **always**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```